# How function reference works in js?

Tags: javascript

Recently I've been trying to use pixi.js for some fun project and I come across a concept that I do not understand at all. Quoting some code:

```
PIXI.loader
.add([
"images/one.png",
"images/two.png",
"images/three.png"
])
.on("progress", loadProgressHandler)
.load(setup);

function loadProgressHandler(loader, resource) {
console.log(`loading: ${resource.url}`);
};
```

How these arguments (loader, resource) are passed to the function since we only pass the reference to it in the event listener? Can someone show a generic implementation beneath that concept?

Comment: loadProgressHandler is passed to the event handler using on, the event is named "progress", if you want to get more detail, add console.dir(loader); console.dir(resource) to your handling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have a function called `callMe` that just prints a number that its given:

```
function callMe(number) {
    console.log(`I'm number: ${number}`);
}
callMe(2);
```

We can create a new variable to that same function, and call the newly created variable. This is possible since it's pointing to the same function that we've created earlier.

```
const callMeAswell = callMe;
callMe(3);
callMeAswell(4);
```

In short, this is what's happing inside the PIXI loaders, except for that it's stored somewhere else for you. Lets create a class to store the numbers and the function that we want to call:

```
function SomeLoader(){
    this.numbers = []; // list of numbers we want to store for later usage
    this.func = null; // function that we want to call when we're done loading
}
SomeLoader.prototype.add = function(number) {
    this.numbers.push(number); // add the number to the list of numbers
}
SomeLoader.prototype.on = function(func) {
    this.func = func; // just store the function for now, but don't do anything with it
}
SomeLoader.prototype.pretendToLoad = function() {
    for(const number of this.numbers) {
        this.func(number); // now we're going to call the function that we've stored (callMe in the example below)
    }
}

const loader = new SomeLoader();
loader.add(5);
loader.add(6);
loader.on(callMe);
loader.pretendToLoad();
```

Or fluently:

```
function SomeLoader(){
    this.numbers = [];
    this.func = null;
}
SomeLoader.prototype.add = function(number) {
    this.numbers.push(number);
    return this;
}
SomeLoader.prototype.on = function(func) {
    this.func = func;
    return this;
}
SomeLoader.prototype.pretendToLoad = function() {
    for(const number of this.numbers) {
        this.func(number);
    }
}

new SomeLoader()
    .add(7)
    .add(8)
    .on(callMe)
    .pretendToLoad();
```

Looks almost the same as the PIXI loaders, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are passed to the function when it is called.

The code which calls that function isn't in the question. It is done somewhere behind the `on` function.

In short: The same way as normal, you just aren't looking at the point where it happens.

```js
const show = value => console.log(value);
const call_callback_with_hello_world = callback => callback("Hello, world");
call_callback_with_hello_world(show);
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Quentin said is correct - adding on to that however...

A generic concept beneath that implemention is called a callback and would look like so:

```js
function Loop(callback, index){
 callback(index);
}

function CallbackFunction(val){
 console.log(val)
}

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 Loop(CallbackFunction, i);
}
```